# SKShapeNode with different rotate axis also with SKPhysicsBody swift

Tags: swift, rotation, skphysicsbody, skshapenode

[image: Rotation near the bottom and center]

I am trying to create a SKshapenode which can rotate with hinge at the bottom like shape on left. But i want that to have its physicsbody where the visual shape is. The Physicsbody is always at the same where i have drawn in blue. Is there a way to move the shape move like a inverted pendulum and hit the ball ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer:
Anchor point is only visual in order to get the SKPhysicalbody to work i had to use SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromPath: Body.path). It will solve the above problem.